# Camel EventNotifierSupport produces duplicated output

Tags: apache-camel

In order to perform performance measure and audit logging on Camel, the AuditEventNotifer  is implemented as below. However, every event is logged twice. For example, message completion event of **31140** is logged twice. Can someone give me a hints on how to resolve the issue?

*Route Definition*

```
from(INBOUND_ENDPOINT).filter(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar")).to(
                "mock:result");
```

*AuditEventNotifer Implementation*

```
@Component
public class AuditEventNotifer extends EventNotifierSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AuditEventNotifer.class);

    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info(event.toString());
    }
```

*Below are the logs produced*

```
15:29:12.497 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31140]]
15:29:12.497 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31140]]
15:29:12.497 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31141]]
15:29:12.497 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31141]]
15:29:12.498 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31142]]
15:29:12.498 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31142]]
15:29:12.498 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31143]]
15:29:12.498 [thread #0 - JmsConsumer[ticket_queue]] INFO  AuditEventNotifer:19 - exchange completed: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:feee:6a24%em1a48e14979b5068a0:31143]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the notifier bean is not configured twice. If the class is annotated with `@Component`, then the bean must **not** be defined in the Spring XML configuration:

<s>`<bean id="auditEventNotifier" class="your.package.AuditEventNotifer" />`</s>

Choose one or the other possibility but not both.

Comment: @LewisWong I replaced my old answer with this one. Please check it, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not overridden the

```
public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event)
```

It prints the message for each state of the event.

Eg: If you want the message to be printed only once when its sent, Check the code block below.

```
@Component
public class AuditEventNotifer extends EventNotifierSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AuditEventNotifer.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
        return event instanceof ExchangeSentEvent;
    }
    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info(event.toString());
    }

}
```